# Вывод текста при условие (if)

Tags: android, java

Почему не работает? Нужно, чтобы в определенную дату выводил текст. Помогите пожалуйста

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    SimpleDateFormat dfDate_day= new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM");

    String dt="";
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    String data = dfDate_day.format(c.getTime());

   String data2 = "09.02"; 
        if(data==data2){

        data = "Happy!";
        }
        tv.setText(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строки нельзя сравнивать оператором **==**

Строки сравниваются методом **equels()**

Для вашего случая:

```
if (data.equels(data2))
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Только equals()
;)